# Вывести элементы массива в кавычках

Tags: массивы, вывод

Есть массив `Array(Мужчинам,Одежда,Брюки)` этот массив нужно вывести в атрибуте `data-group` в таком виде:

```
data-groups="[&quot;"Мужчинам"&quot;,&quot;"Одежда"&quot;,&quot;"Брюки"&quot;]"
```

Попробовал так:

```
data-groups="[<?$join = implode('","', $array);echo "&quot;".$join."&quot;";?>]"
```

Выводит такое:

```
data-groups="["Женщинам","одежда","Сарафаны&quot;]"
```

Подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
<?php
$array = array( 'Мужчинам', 'Одежда', 'Брюки' );

$data = 'data-groups="[&quot;"' . implode( '"&quot;,&quot; "', $array ) . ' "&quot;]" ';

echo $data;

/*
Результат
data-groups="[&quot;"Мужчинам"&quot;,&quot; "Одежда"&quot;,&quot; "Брюки "&quot;]" 
*/

?>
```